# Yo me ofendiera si... o, yo me ofendería si... ? (Pretérito imperfecto vs Condicional simple)

Tags: pretérito, condicional

¿Es correcto que alguien diga por ejemplo:

> Yo me **ofendiera** si ganas.

En vez de decir:

> Yo me **ofendería** si ganas.

En caso de que no, ¿por qué?

Comment: Para mi la pregunta sería por qué preferirías el pretérito imperfecto si tienes un tiempo que es _condicional_ y el sentido de esa frase es claramente condicional. Es la pregunta si el pretérito imperfecto puede sustituir al condicional? Es decir, que lo normal sería que la respuesta fuese "no". En caso de poder usar otro tiempo que el condicional para una frase condicional, por qué sucede eso y en qué casos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes una frase que es claramente un condicional (dependiendo de este resultado - si ganas o no- sucede esta otra -yo me enfado-) lo suyo es usar el tiempo condicional. Puede el pretérito imperfecto (o quizá otro tiempo verbal) sustituir al condicional en algún caso? Ten también en cuenta que hay un pretérito imperfecto simple (que es solo para acciones en el pasado) y uno de subjuntivo, y tú ahí estas usando el de subjuntivo.

En este enlace sobre el [condicional simple](http://www.timandangela.org.uk/spanish/19-condicional-simple), que incluye usos como

- Para expresar deseos. (ej Me gustaría viajar a la India. Desearía comer chocolate.)
- Para dar consejos y sugerencias. (Ej Debería hablar más español. Tendría que ... ¿Cuáles te comprarías tú? Me compraría los azules. Yo que tú me compraría...)
- Expresar cortesía o suavizar peticiones. (Ej ¿Podría hablar con usted? Querría un billete para Madrid. ¿Te importaría darme fuego?.)
- Para expresar duda o probabilidad en el pasado lejano (con pt. imperfecto y pt. indefinido, pero no el pt. perfecto).
  (Ej ¿A qué hora te acostaste anoche?
  Me acosté a las 2 (un tiempo exacto).
  Sobre las 2 = Me acostaría a las 2 = Serían las 2.)
- ¿Cuántos años tenía cuando la conociste?
  (Ej. Probablemente tenía 23. Tendría como 23.)
- Para expresar un futuro desde un punto de vista pasado.
  (Ej Me dijiste que llegarías sobre las 5)

Para responder del todo a tu pregunta, el pretérito imperfecto (simple) expresa acciones en el pasado. Las condiciones son situaciones hipotéticas, por lo cual con ellas vas a usar los tiempos condicionales o el subjuntivo

> Si yo me ofendiera por eso, sería lo lógico.

Con el subjuntivo sí que puede expresar por ejemplo opinión, deseo, prohibiciones, permisos, consejos y sobre todo **probabilidad y duda**, que entra dentro del terreno del condicional. Es decir que, debido a que tiene un significado subjetivo porque no está sucediendo en realidad o porque está sucediendo en forma irreal, no se puede determinar el tiempo de la acción.

> Dudo que se **ofendiera** por eso

Ten en cuenta que que según la RAE, la alternancia de usar el  pretérito pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo en las oraciones condicionales está permitida, es decir que tiene pleno uso decir

> Si hubiese hecho buen tiempo hubiera salido (junto a habría salido).

Como recuerda [esta web](http://web.abo.fi/csk/proj/vkk/caminando/5/recordando/condicionalysubjuntivo.htm) se da preferencia al condicional compuesto en estos casos, es decir que en casos  de relación con el subjuntivo, es preferible siempre la forma potencial en los tiempos compuestos. Es decir que no se debería decir:

> Si me hubieras pedido que lo comentara, yo lo hubiese hecho.

Es más correcto

> Si me hubieras pedido que lo comentara, yo lo habría hecho.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo pero me parece que una respuesta más sencilla sería mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Existe un uso condicional del imperfecto. En [esta web](https://facultystaff.richmond.edu/~ahermida/verbos1.htm) se resume muy bien:

> Imperfecto-futuro: sustituye al condicional en la apódosis de
>   oraciones condicionales. Es de uso coloquial. Ej.: Si tuviera dinero,
>   me lo compraba.

Sin embargo, en este caso particular suena realmente mal, y no es para menos: fíjate que en el ejemplo anterior se refiere siempre a oraciones compuestas, en las que una de ellas es condicional (Aunque se omita).

Si añades una así como contexto a tu ejemplo, puede valer, al igual que en la cita que te he puesto arriba; pero así solo no parece un uso correcto.

Answer (score 1):

> Yo me ofendiera si ganas

no es correcto porque el verbo condicional correcto es *ofendería*.

Sin embargo, con una corrección, sí podrás usar "ofendiera" (subjuntivo del pasado):

> Si yo me ofendiera cada vez que ganas, pues no tendría caso jugar.